# string[16] fails on 17-character string?

Tags: ruby

```
specialChars = "]%#$!_.+?~&[*/^;@"

puts(specialChars[16])
```

Prints a blank line. Why could this be? Do I need to escape some character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#` is a reserved character used for string interpolation when delimiting with ":

```
# Example
puts "My name is #{my_name}!"
```

If you use '' instead of "", string interpolation is disabled and you can use it normally:

```
# The "" has been replaced with ''
specialChars = ']%#$!_.+?~&[*/^;@'
puts specialChars[16]
# => '@'
```

Comment: Huh, I'd heard about that, but I assumed it would function normally without a `{` after it. Seems rather odd.

Comment: @LucasPhillips if it's followed by a character that looks like it might be part of a variable name, it'll still use interpolation. e.g. `"#@foo"` would use the value of `@foo`. In your case it's using the contents of the system variable `$!`

Comment: ^ I literally just discovered this in `pry`. Congrats on beating me to the mark replying ;)

Comment: Like instance variables, accessing an undefined global variable returns `nil`. It is therefore interpolating the value of `$1`, `nil`, into your string!

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Cronin has it right: the `#$!` gets interpreted as a string interpolation command.  You should really be running Ruby code like this in IRB so you can easily see the results:

```
irb(main):001:0> specialChars = "]%#$!_.+?~&[*/^;@"
=> "]%_.+?~&[*/^;@"
```

Another way to see the results be to run `p specialChars` or equivalently `puts specialChars.inspect`.  Inspecting objects that behave oddly using these techniques is a good habit.

The pound sign (#) is normally allowed in strings, but if it is in a double-quoted string and is followed by a `$`, then it will do string interpolation.  In your case, it was grabbing the global variable `$!`, converting it to a string with `.to_s`, and a sticking it in the string.  Your code was equivalent to:

```
specialChars = "]%#{$!}_.+?~&[*/^;@"
```

Here are some more examples of string interpolation:

```
"Hello, #{name}!"   # method or local variable
"Hello, #@name!"    # instance variable
"Hello, #$name!"    # global variable
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, the character `#` is interpreted as interpolation when a sigil character i.e. `$` or `@` follows. Besides using single quotes to avoid that, another way is to rearrange the characters such as:

```
"]%#!_.+?~&[*/^;@$"
```